# Docker build fails unpredictably with minor or no changes to docker file

Tags: docker

This is a frustating situation where the docker build command fails frequently and without reason. There command being run is `docker build -t imgtag .`. The error goes away if I do the following:

- `rm ~/.docker/config.json`
- `docker login`
- restart computer

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I can't keep restarting my computer to work with docker. Any help appreciated. I don't want to build without cache every time Thank you.

```
[internal] load .dockerignore
  transferring context: 2B
[internal] load build definition from dockerfile
  transferring dockerfile: 1.69kB
ERROR [internal] load metadata for nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:23.03-py3
[internal] load metadata for nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:23.03-py3:
dockerfile:2
   2 | >>> FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:23.03-py3
   3 |
   4 |     SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized
```

Comment: `docker pull nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:23.03-py3` works without issues.

Comment: Let me give it a try. As far as I understand, this is a rate limit issue? That would explain the random failings.